# can't populate the table using Ajax and CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to populate the table using datatable plugin, ajax, and jquery. please help!

in the table the Loading word appears but no data from the sql is displaying. It only shows the word loading. but when I clicked the table it tells "No data in the table"

this is my jquery code

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    'serverside': true,
    'ajax': {
        'url': '<?php echo site_url('members/viewall'); ?>',
        'type': 'POST',
    },
    'columns': [
        {'data': 'firstName'},
        {'data': 'lastName'},
        {'data': 'gender'},
        {'data': 'address'},
        {'data': 'dob'},
        {'data': 'id'},
    ]
});
```

in my controller

```
public function viewAll()
{
    $results = $this->membersdata->getAllMembers();         
    $data = array();

    foreach($results as $row)
    {

        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what is (or isn't) happening?

Comment: in the table the Loading word appears but no data from the sql is displaying. It only shows the word loading. but when I clicked the table it tells "No data in the table"